# AWS Resource policy on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm trying to [use Resource Policy IP whitelisting to protect API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html). I have following questions and am not able to find public doc for these:

- Can I make resource policy only effect to a specific stage's API gateway? If yes, how?
- How much time does propagation need after I make a change on the policy?
- Can Resource Policy be used on API with protocol WebSocket and endpoint type Regional? (Looks like not, I don't see option of it)
- Does Resource Policy have version control? (looks like it does not)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I make resource policy only effect to a specific stage's API gateway? If yes, how?
yes, example from [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html#apigateway-resource-policies-source-ip-address-example).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::account-id-2:user/Alice",
            "account-id-2"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id-1:api-id/stage/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

How much time does propagation need after I make a change on the policy?

- you need to deploy the api again, you can do it from aws console

Can Resource Policy be used on API with protocol WebSocket and endpoint type Regional? 
(Looks like not, I don't see option of it)

- i don't see why not, whatever the type you choose, it is still powered by API Gateway.

Does Resource Policy have version control? (looks like it does not)

- Looks like it does not

Comment: Thanks! I dived deeper and found Websocket API Gateway supports IAM and Lambda Auth only. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-control-access.html

Comment: i have never used websocket API before. But according to the documentation you shared, you seems to be right about that. But using the lambda authentication, you should be able to integrate with other authentication providers or implement your own authentication mechanisms.